# Inconvertible types; cannot cast android.app.fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio

I am a newbie to programming in android studio, I am trying to work with Google Maps (setting up destination, routes and more) in a navigation drawer, where I have multiple fragments, and one specifically for Google maps, I was Having trouble to use markers and work on the map with the `onMapReady()`    method, I was able to find that instead i should use the `onActivityCreated()` method, but once i started working on it, it started giving me the following error: Inconvertible types, cannot cast `android.app.Fragment` to `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`. in the following line of code: `mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);` as well gives me a second error: Wrong 2nd argument type, Found: `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` Required: `android.app.Fragment` in the following line of code: `fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();`. Unfortunately i havent been able to find an answer or solution to this problem and will appreciate your help.

Here is my the complete code for the fragment where the map is located:

```
package demo.mapas;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.usuario.mapas.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

/**
 * Created by USUARIO on 3/12/2016.
 */
public class opcion1Fragment extends Fragment  {
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_option1, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if(mapFragment == null){
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
        } else {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `opcion1Fragment` is extending from `android.app.Fragment;`. But you need to use class from `android.support.v4.app`. So you need to:

1. Change your import from: `import android.app.Fragment;` to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
2. Change your import from `import android.app.FragmentManager;` to `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

And your problem will be fixed.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That fixed the problem! Deeply Appreciated!! @g2o

Comment: Glad to help...please mark the question as solved ;)

Comment: not working with 'import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;' @GueorguiObregon